# Multiple Inventories Not Working - No Hosts Found

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm using the Ansible EC2 dynamic inventory script to access my hosts in EC2. The hosts I am looking for have a tag named `sisyphus_environment` with a value of `development` and another tag named `sisyphus_project` with a value of `reddot`, so I need the intersection of these tags.

However, I can't even seem to get filtering on one tag working properly with the EC2 inventory.

I can clearly find the instances in question using the AWS CLI:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters \
        Name=tag:sisyphus_environment,Values=development \
        Name=tag:sisyphus_project,Values=reddot \
        Name=tag:sisyphus_role,Values=nginx | \
    jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | { InstanceId: .InstanceId }'
{
  "InstanceId": "i-deadbeef"
}
{
  "InstanceId": "i-cafebabe"
}
```

I'm attempting to do the same thing with Ansible expressed as a static group consisting of dynamic members filtered by these tags.

My ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
retry_files_enabled = false
roles_path = roles:galaxy_roles
inventory = inventory/

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

My EC2 inventory [is directly sourced from upstream](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py) along with the [ec2.ini](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.ini).

My inventory directory looks like this:

```
$ tree inventory/
inventory/
├── ec2.ini
├── ec2.py
└── inventory.ini

0 directories, 3 files
```

I had to name `inventory` with an `.ini` extension, otherwise Ansible was trying to load it as YAML and failing.

My `inventory/inventory.ini` file looks like this:

```
[tag_sisyphus_project_reddot]
# blank

[reddot:children]
tag_sisyphus_project_reddot
```

This was done [similar to Ansible's documentation on the matter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#static-groups-of-dynamic-groups). Unfortunately, this simple thing fails:

```
$ inventory/ec2.py --refresh-cache
...
$ ansible reddot -m command -a 'echo true'
 [WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

If I query by the tag, I get results:

```
$ ansible tag_sisyphus_project_reddot -m command -a 'echo true'
10.0.0.1 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
true
...
```

Is there a step I'm missing?

My Ansible version:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.2.0.0
  config file = /home/naftuli/Documents/Development/ansible-reddot/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```